# Inserting record and fetching key in realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the below code to insert new entry in Firebase realtime database. It inserts the record, but it is returning wrong key. Here is the code:

```
  createUser() {
    firebase.database().ref('users/').push({
        age: "30",
        email: "sa@sa.com",
        name: "saurabh"
    });

      // Get a key for a new Post.
  var Key = firebase.database().ref('users/').push().key;
console.log(Key);
  }
```

Once the user is created, it should return the right key but it is returning something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `push()`, it's going to generate a new random key.  It will never return the same one.  You're calling `push()` at least twice in the code you show here, so you can expect to get two different keys.

It seems to me that your function `createUser()` should return the DatabaseReference that was returned by `push()`, so that the caller can make use of it if needed.

Comment: alright, so how do i get the key of the saved object ?

Comment: You have to remember the key you got from the push, or make a query for it using the child values you added.